# Is it possible to search devices by services in Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to another iOS device which is acting as a peripheral in background mode. I know that you cannot connect via the name of the device because `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` is ignored in background mode. But **I would like to know if the central** (which is another iOS device in foreground mode) **can search for services directly and get the UUID of the service's device to then be able to connect to this device?** Or am I in the obligation to be connected to another device to be able to scan this device's service?

Comment: searching by advertised services is the *only* way to search for devices; In foreground mode you can search for `nil` to find all advertising peripherals, but the recommended approach is to search for peripherals that are explicitly advertising the service you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for your response. Searching by services is what I understood too, but I wanted to know if there was a specific function to search peripheral by services or if I needed to connect to every device and then browse through their services to know which is the one I'm searching.

Comment: You specify the services when you call `scanForPeripherals`

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry for the dumb question and thank you for your quick responses!